# How to display views of list custom settings in lightning component as it is?

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning, customsetting

> I have a custom setting , say ListCustomSetting__c and 5 views are defined for it in salesforce org. I want to build a lightning commponent which will have a dropdown showing these 5 views , and on selecting any one of these, records in that particular view should be shown. In short, I want to replicate the standard salesforce page displayed on click of "manage" as it is in lightning.
>
> I am able to fetch custom setting records depending on view selected in lightning component controller, but I am thinking that instead I fetch list view itself(like we fetch custom object) from salesforce, which will help me show it as it is in component and save me effort of logic to display fields depending on view selected in lightning component.
>
> Does anybody have any idea how we can fetch records directly from list view?